# What is the probability that no more than $200$ products from $1200$ are defected

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Question goes as follows:

> It is known that $0.15$ of products sold by store are defected in some way and  have to be replaced. The shop has $1200$ products in storage. What is the probability that an order of $1000$ and the replaced products of that order (because of defects) can be made (I assume with the 1200 products in storage).

My reasoning goes as follows. Since we sell $1000$ products from the storage, we have to figure out what is the probability that the number of defected products is less or equal to $200$. I think this follows Binomial distribution but since $min:(np,np(1-p))>5$ I tried to arpoximate it with normal distribution;$$Mean = .15*1000=150$$ $$Var=1000*.15*.85=127.5$$ $$N(150,127.5)$$
X = number of products defected

$$P(X\le200)=\phi(\frac{200.5-150}{\sqrt{127.5}})=\phi(4.472)\approx0.999996$$

This answer for me feels too certan. The $4.4$ siqma event isn't even on the spreadsheet I am using (had to use excel).

So my question is can some one check if I am right and if not give me some hint what to do differently?

Comment: Well, keep in mind that $30$ (or so) of the residual $200$ are defective as well.

Comment: I think you'll be better off phrasing the question as "what is the probability that no more than $200$ of the $1200$ are defective?" .

Comment: @lulu so I should I should use $1200$ when calculating mean and variance?

Comment: Well, I would.  Yes.